# Maximum number of vertical subplots in plotly figure

Tags: python, bar-chart, plotly, figure

I can't seem to get the spacing right for vertical subplots in plotly. Currently, my figure looks like this:

[image]

There are a couple of things that I would like to fix:

1) Increase the amount of space between subplots, and just make the figure larger

2) Increase the size of each y-axis so that the tick labels aren't overlapping.

I don't see any arguments in the `plotly.tools.make_subplots` function that controls the size of the figure. If there is some way to make the figure larger so that each plot has more space, that would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A minimal reproducible example

```
import plotly
plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode()
import random
rows = 10
traces = [[random.random() for j in range(100)] for i in range(rows)]

fig = plotly.tools.make_subplots(rows=rows, cols=1)
for i in range(1, rows + 1):
    p = plotly.graph_objs.Bar(y=traces[i - 1], showlegend=False)
    fig.append_trace(p, i, 1)
plotly.offline.iplot(fig)
```

produces

[image]

> 1) Increase the amount of space between subplots, and just make the
>   figure larger
>
> 2) Increase the size of each y-axis so that the tick labels aren't overlapping.

You can use `vertical_spacing` in combination with `layout['height']` to address both issues at the same time.

```
fig = plotly.tools.make_subplots(rows=rows, cols=1, vertical_spacing=0.5/rows)
fig['layout'].update(height=1000)
```

[image]